# How do I make a valid config.xml for my Phonegap project?

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I am [trying to include the WebIntent plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374687/184108) for my Phonegap Android app. In the documentation for installing it, it says one needs to add a line to the `res/xml/config.xml` file. However, I have no `config.xml` file.

I did a little searching, and it seems that people say it's okay to simply create a `config.xml`, so I did, using some guidelines from examples I came across. However, the Android Developer Tools interface is showing red Xs and red squiggly error lines all over it, indicating that it's full of mistakes. Here's what it looks like:

[image: invalid config.xml]

What should my `config.xml` file look like?

Or, alternatively, if there's a better tutorial or method for including the WebIntent plugin, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config.xml should look like this in Phonegap 2.7 or above.  Older versions don't use the feature tags.  This is the out of the box config and has everything in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
    version   = "2.0.0">
<name>APP NAME</name>

<description>
    DESCRIPTION
</description>

<author href="YOUR URL" email="YOUR EMAIL">
    YOUR NAME
</author>

<access origin="*"/>

<!-- <content src="http://mysite.com/myapp.html" /> for external pages -->
<content src="index.html" />

<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<!--
  <preference name="splashscreen" value="resourceName" />
  <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xFFF" />
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
  <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
-->

<feature name="App">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Geolocation">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Device">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Accelerometer">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Compass">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Media">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Camera">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Contacts">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
</feature>
<feature name="File">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Storage">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Capture">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Battery">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Echo">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Globalization">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
</feature>
<!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->
<plugins>
<plugin name="WebIntent" value="com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent" />
</plugins>
</widget>
```

Comment: Thanks! One question - do I remove all the `<feature>` tags for all the ones I'm not using, like "Storage"?

Comment: You can yes, but it does appear to still include the code when built however, so I leave it in.  

Remove unneeded features from the AndroidManifest.xml so when you submit to Google Play and a user installs the app, it doesn't tell them it needs permission to X.

You'll see the options in <users-permission android:name="...">

Comment: Also, you'll need to add an intent filter to your AndroidManifest.xml file, but that should hopefully be in your instructions.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I add this XML file, it is equally covered in red Xs and squiggly lines, and Eclipse won't let me compile.

Comment: What are the errors? If you click the red icon in the left margin it should tell you.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm using a version of Phonegap that is too old. I'm [trying to figure out how to update to the latest version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18426864/184108).

Comment: Good luck. I'm using 2.9 and found it quite easy to upgrade, just follow the instructions on the phonegap docs site-you may need to follow a number if steps if your version is very old. OR  just create a new project with the command line tool and copy the contents of the assets folder from the old to the new one, then include the plugin again.

Comment: I think I've finally upgraded to 2.9, and the xml file is clear and without errors. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My solution upon the initial creation of the project:

Instead of creating the project through the PhoneGap Desktop App, I built the project using PhoneGap cli by typing in:

> > phonegap create "projectName"

This created the project with config.xml successfully. Now you can open the created file using the PhoneGap Desktop App.

**Reference:** [http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/11/13/phonegap-cli-3-6-3/](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/3-create-your-app/cli/)