# ERROR: config.xml is missing in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have a problem in phonegap. I was developing a project in phonegap and it was running some days before. Now when i tried to run the same app, i am getting

```
ERROR: config.xml is missing.  Add res/xml/plugins.xml to your project.
```

As i can see i have this file inside my res folder. And the thing is i have already developed this application, i just wanted to do some minor changes in my app but getting the above error.

I have updated my sdk some days ago will that can cause some problem? I really dont know.. :(

**UPDATE**

I tried to remove the `cordova.jar` file and deleted the `config.xml` file from my app and then again added it but the problem is persisted.

I am using phonegap 2.9 in my project.

Comment: 2.9 is quite outdated now, but anyhow, you can check config.xml in your www folder (not the one inside platforms/android/.. but in parent folder of platforms). Perhaps that's the one missing.

Comment: Refer this--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414830/how-do-i-make-a-valid-config-xml-for-my-phonegap-project